# How to read password protected excel file with python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

As the title states, my question is how can I read a password protected excel file in python without any user input?

The simple solution I found on reddit which first decrypts the file and then encrypts it again, however, it requires user to manually input password both time: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/rwy14d/read_passwordprotected_excel_and_save_to/

Moreover, is there an alternative method which lets you just read the file in pandas without the need of decrypting and then encrypting the file?

code from the reddit link:

```
import win32com.client as win32
#filename should include fill path to file
def unprotect_xlsx(filename, pw_str):
    xcl = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = xcl.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, False, None, pw_str)
    xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs(filename, None, '', '')
    xcl.DisplayAlerts = True
    xcl.Quit()

def protect_xlsx(filename, pw_str):
    xcl = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb =  xcl.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs(filename, None, '', pw_str)
    xcl.DisplayAlerts = True
    xcl.Quit()
```

Comment: Are you planning to hard-code the password then?

Comment: Yes, I am planning to hardcode it. I have the password the problem is since I have multiple files it is a pain to input it everytime.